# Can we define the equality as $a=b$ iff $\frac{a}{b}=1$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Well, The title i guess is enough to get what i'm looking for:

I'm wondering if we can define equality of let's say $a$ and $b$ that the devision of $a$ over $b$ or $b$ over $a$ is $1$ :
$$a=b \implies \frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{a}=1$$
if that is true then why it doesn't holds for $0$ case :
$$\frac{0}{0}\neq1$$

Comment: How do you define $\frac ab{\color{red}=} 1$ then?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What do you mean ?

Comment: We are not trying to define $\frac{a}{b}=1$ we are trying to define $a=b$

Comment: @ Antaraz : I agree with Hagen. When you don't have a definition of "equality" and try to define it, you can not use the "equality" itself.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac 00 \neq 1.$$ Indeed $\frac 00$ is undefined. But $a = b$ when $a = b=0$.

So you *cannot* say $a = b \implies \frac ab = 1$.

What you *can* say is  $$\frac ab = 1 \implies a = b$$

It's the "if and only if* that's problematic, for the reason at the top.

Comment: You mean that's true in one direction.

Comment: Yes, exactly. One direction, but not both. So you can say "if....then" for the direction that holds. But you cannot say "if and only if" (i.e., you cannot use $\iff$).